# WPF Window: Need to use SizeToContent up to a specific Size

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF window with content that can vary it's size (a DataGrid).
SizeToContent works great for small Datasets, but for large Datasets the window gets too big on initial display.

How would I use SizeToContent in conjuction with a Maximum initial size of 600x600 (the window should still be able to be resized larger manually or maximized). Also the window can be hidden and reshown multiple times and should retain it's size when reshown (that is already the default behavior I'd like to retain).

```
        myWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to temporarily set the MaxWidth and MaxHeight on first render, but then turn it off after the first render. The problem is, if you turn off those values after the first render, then your SizeToContent will kick in and the window will resize to the large Dataset again!

To alleviate this, you will also have to turn off your SizeToContent after the first render. Here's a solution that worked for me:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="_72120715.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_72120715"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" MaxWidth="600" MaxHeight="600">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Stuff { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ContentRendered += MainWindow_ContentRendered;
        DataContext = this;
        Stuff = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Stuff.Add($"This is stuff {i}");
        }
    }

    private void MainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the MaxWidth/MaxHeight so that you can manually resize larger
        MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity; 
        MaxHeight = double.PositiveInfinity;
        // Clear the SizeToContent so that it doesn't automatically resize to large datasets
        SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
    }
}
```

Comment: Greetings Tam, that didn't work, the window isn't resizable beyond the initial 60x600 or maximizabe. I heard that window parameters can't be changed after it's shown (some parameters).

Comment: It worked for me. I was able to resize the window width and height larger after it initially rendered at a possible max of 600x600. The `Listbox` in my example showed a vertical scrollbar to indicate it hit the max height of 600, but I was then able to resize it greater than 600. Did you try a clean test app, or did you try putting it into your app?

Comment: I'm creating a subwindow in codebehind and I followed the your example perfectly.
That initial max size is stuck somehow.

Comment: There must be something different about what you're doing and what I'm doing. I have zero issues resizing the window. [Here, I have uploaded the full working source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RCFHw9N50HvtZOfR5e4dm-j9cbrvrA3a/view?usp=sharing). Both the MainWindow and the SubWindow are able to resize after initially showing 600x600. Try it and tell me if it doesn't work for you, because it works for me.

Comment: And [here's a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tXrnmFYyL3JjpKuKcayINy0CGAmfSMYP/view?usp=sharing) proving my solution is working.

Comment: I tried your code again, confirmed, it DID work. Thanks so much! Brilliant Solution.